# knockout ChartJs

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Использую вот такую библиотеку: http://www.chartjs.org/

HTML:

```
<script type="text/html" id="statisticsView">
    <div class="row">
        <div data-bind="myChart: true"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
        ko.bindingHandlers.myChart = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, viewModel, bindingContext) {    

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');       
            canvas.width = 600;           
            canvas.height = 600;
            element.appendChild(canvas);
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
        }
    };
```

Проблема в том, что ChartJs работает со свойствами ctx.canvas.offsetWidth и         ctx.canvas.offsetHeight, а они равны нулю, и вылетает ошибка, как можно это исправить?

```
<div data-bind="myChart: true">
    <canvas id="chart-area" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>

    ko.bindingHandlers.myChart = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var canvas = element.children["chart-area"];
            console.log(canvas.offsetWidth);//0
        }
    };
```

Нашел один не хороший способ:

```
    this.go = function () {
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById('test'), {
            myChart: true
        });
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.myChart = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            //var canvas = element.children["chart-area"];
            //console.log(canvas.offsetWidth);//0
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = 600;
            canvas.height = 600;
            element.appendChild(canvas);

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            console.log(ctx.canvas.offsetWidth);//600
        }
    };
```

По всей видимости, нужно отложить как то биндинг, но вот как сделать это красиво?

Comment: Попробуйте сперва добавить элемент в DOM, что бы его было видно. должен появиться offsetWidth.

Comment: element.appendChild(canvas); - добавление элемент в DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

немного bad practice:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.myChart = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, viewModel, bindingContext) {    

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');       
        canvas.width = 600;           
        canvas.height = 600;
        element.appendChild(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // откладываем логику чарта, а меж тем произойдёт отрисовка
        setTimeout(function() {
             new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

Или:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.myChart = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, viewModel, bindingContext) {    

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');       
        canvas.width = 600;           
        canvas.height = 600;
        element.appendChild(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // вызываем перерисовку, канва должна отрисоваться на странице
        var width = element.offsetWidth; 

        new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
    }
};
```

Comment: Первый способ не подошел, после setTimeout поставил console.log(ctx.canvas.offsetWidth) и получил 0.

Comment: Нужно ставить не после setTimeout, а в него самого

Comment: А второй способ?

Comment: Оба способа не подошли

Comment: Ну вот, а говорил, что подошел ) смотри, тут, вроде, всё ок http://jsfiddle.net/tzmnopws/